# If "A", "B", "X", and "R" respectively denote "divided by", "added to", "subtracted from", and "multiplied by", then evaluate "18R12A4X8B6"

Tags: arithmetic

> If
>
> - "A" denotes "divided by"
> - "B" denotes "added to"
> - "X" denotes "subtracted from"
> - "R" denotes "multiplied by"
>
> then
>    $$18R12A4X8B6\;=\;\text{?}$$
>
> $\left(A\right)50 \quad\left(B\right)102 \quad \left(C\right)45 \quad \left(D\right)32$

My Approach $\Longrightarrow$ I tried it in two ways

First approach: 
$$18\times\left[\left(8+6\right)-\left(12\div4\right)\right]=198$$

Second approach: $$18\times12\div4-8+6=40$$

Comment: For example 6X4 would be 4-6 not 6-4, since x is "subtracted from".

Comment: What were your instructions?  Were you *expected* to do this from left to right?  If not what *were* the rules.  The answer can be anything you want depending on what rules you were given.

Comment: Okay I'd do it, with coffemaths obeservation, as $18R12 = 18*12 = 216$.  $216A4 = 216\div 4 = 54$.  And $54X8=8 -54 = -46$. And $-46B6 = -46+6 = -40$.  I don't like to ever call a question a stupid question but for this I'll make an exception.

Comment: @fleablood the question is from math magician compition.no more instructions are given .I have  provided everything I know

Comment: @fleablood I agree

Comment: @fleablood one thing that troubles me more is that why I am not getting even a wrong answer from the given options

Comment: It depends on the order of operations.  If you do it by the standard arithmetic model this is $(8+6) -18\times \frac {12}4$.  If you do this in strict left to right the answer is $-40$.  Obviously you aren't supposed to do either (else why the *idiocy* of replacing the symbols) but it's ambiguous as to what order the intuitively expect.  You can try them in different order until you get something but life's too short to waste on stupid activities and the people who asked this don't deserve your attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

18*12/4-8+6
=18*3-8+6
=54-8+6
=44+6
=50
Correct option is A

Comment: How is 54-8+6=44+6 ? Shouldn't it be 46 + 6??